# AWS CLI in Windows EC2 cannot use role to access S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, command-line-interface, amazon-iam, role

I am very new to AWS. I created an IAM role which has full access to **S3**. I assigned this role to a **Windows Server** EC2 instance. I then installed **CLI** on that instance. I then remoted into that instance using RDP, and started a CMD windows, and typed in

```
aws s3 ls
```

It complained that

```
Unable to locate credentials. You can configure credentials by running "aws configure".
```

Now that this EC2 has been assigned the role that has full access to S3, why can't I directly access S3?

Comment: You have done everything correctly, so the result is strange. Does the role name appear if you use a web browser on that EC2 instance to go to `http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/`? If so, append the role name to that URL and confirm whether security credentials are shown (eg Access Key & Secret Key).

Comment: The request timed out every time

Comment: The metadata URL timed out? Do you get anything if you open `http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/` in a browser on the EC2 instance? It's starting to sound like the IAM Role is *not* attached to the instance.

Comment: No I got nothing from the browser within the EC2 instance - it timed out.

Comment: I double checked the IAM role attached to the EC2: it has AmazonS3FullAccess and AdministratorAccess.

Comment: Something sounds very strange on your instance. That URL will work for any Amazon EC2 instance. Try booting up a new instance and you'll see that [instance metadata](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html) will work.

Comment: Remeber it is a Windows Server EC2. I have tried to launched multiple instances from the same AMI. None worked. Shall I create a brand-new instance?

Comment: Thank you John Rotenstein for your help. You pointed me to the right direction. I created a new instance from scratch, and everything worked. The previous instance I installed IIS and ASP.NET on it. Would it be possibly the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you John Rotenstein for your help. You pointed me to the right direction. I created a new instance from scratch, and everything worked. The previous instance I installed IIS and ASP.NET on it. Would it be possibly the reason?

Comment: You are certainly welcome to install IIS and ASP.NET -- that should not "break" the instance. It's hard to know what might have caused the problem -- but it's often easier to start with a fresh instance and load the software again. In fact, this is the best practice method, since it means you know how to rebuild the instance in future.

Comment: I am facing the same problem at present. Please tell me what did you do to get rid of the problem.

Answer (score 3):

To use AWS CLI with IAM Roles, you create a [named profile](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-roles.html). Instead of configuring this profile with credentials, you specify the ARN of the role and the name of the profile that has access to it.

Comment: Thank you Ashan. I will have a look. However in a Linux EC2 what I did will work. Why doesn't it work in Windows Server EC2?

Answer (score 3):

I stumbled across this post. The reason you get this message is because what @John Rotenstein stated, the server can't reach the metadata.

Running `aws config list` will show that you do not have any credentials as the message states. This means that the server can't the following:

```
# 169.254.169.254 is for metadata service
# 169.254.169.250 is for KmsInstanceVpc1
# 169.254.169.251 is for KmsInstanceVpc2
```

To fix this. It is best to just remove the routes and add them again.

```
"169.254.169.254/32", "169.254.169.253/32", "169.254.169.251/32", "169.254.169.250/32", "169.254.169.249/32", "169.254.169.123/32"
```

Running a `aws config list` will show that the credentials have been added.

I find that [btuanexpress.net script](https://github.com/tuanba2203/btuanexpress.net/blob/master/fix_ec2_instance_netroutes.ps1) to fix this issue within Windows helps

Comment: This was the only thing that fixed my issue when running on Windows Server 2019. Was finally able to resolve http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/

Comment: Script was a lifesaver after not being able to reach Instance Meta Data